# How could I morph one 3D object into another using shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

For the latest Ludum Dare competition the theme was shapeshifting, so my idea involved simple morphing from one geometric shape to another.

So what I did was I made a few objects in Blender with the same vertex count. In OpenGL I made separate VAOs for each object and one additional VAO (with *dynamic draw* attributes) for the "morphing" object. Every frame, while the player is shapeshifting, I would upload interpolated vertex data, between the current object and the target object, into this extra VAO and then render. Otherwise just render the object's corresponding VAO.
Morphing looked like this:

[image: Morphing shapes]

(The vertices have a different ordering, so morphing is not "smooth")

Since I had little time I just made something quick and dirty but now I think this is not a great way of doing this process, because I have to upload a lot of data to the GPU every frame. And it doesn't look scalable either, if I ever wanted to draw multiple morphing objects at different morphing stages.

As a first step to improve this process I would like to move those interpolation calcs into the shaders.
I could perhaps store the data for all objects in a single VAO, in separate attributes, and then select which of the attributes to interpolate from.

But I was wondering: is there a way to somehow send multiple (two) objects/buffers into the shaders, along with an interpolation rate uniform, and then in the shaders I would do the interpolation?

Comment: Create a buffer that has both objects in it

Comment: @teivaz That's a good idea in the case that I only have one morphing object. But if I were to have multiple objects, in the worst case I might have to create multiple VAOs for every possible combination.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for the tessellation part of the pipeline. There are always Compute shaders and CUDA/OpenCL interop for the stuff that does not fit into classic pipeline well.

Comment: @aslg from your example it is clear that you have only two object at a time. Create this buffer for only a current pair

Answer (score 5):

You can create a buffer that holds several coordinates for each vertex. Just like normally you have coordinates, normals, texture coordinates you can have coordinate1, coordinate2, coordinate3 etc. Then in the shader you can have a uniform variable that says which to use.

With two it's of course easy since the uniform will be from zero to one and you just multiply the first coordinate with it and add the second multiplied with (1.0 - value).

Then just make sure you create the meshes from the same base shape and they will morph nicely.

Also if you use normals, make sure you have several normals and interpolate between them also.

The minus in this is that the more data you put through the more skipping in memory the shader has to do so it might not be the prettiest solution if you have a lot of forms.